# jsondecodeerror django after deploying on heroku server the django app

Tags: json, django, heroku, error-handling, server

JSONDecodeError at /vaccine/handle_vaccine_slots/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://systemofreckoning.herokuapp.com/vaccine/handle_vaccine_slots/
Django Version: 3.2.2
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py, line 355, in raw_decode
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
'/app',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 20 May 2021 09:18:42 +0000

Comment: We need more details here please. Share the code that is in your views.py file to begin with.

Comment: Hi @ANINDO, that's unrelated to the question but please turn the debug mode off when you are deploying your application. By accessing http://systemofreckoning.herokuapp.com/vaccine/handle_vaccine_slots/ someone can get the ENV variables that you are using like DB name and DB url.